# Style Trigger for Keyboard Focus

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a window with multiple buttons/textboxes.  When the window is tabbed through I want a way to visually style the controls when they receive the keyboard focus similar to

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BasicBrush}" />
</Trigger>
```

I thought there would be a `IsKeyboardFocus` or similar but couldn't find it.  Does anyone know of a way to do this without handling events in code-behind?

Comment: It looks like setting the FocusVisualStyle property is the way to go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Brian has suggested in the comments, it sounds like you are looking for the [`FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This lets you specify a `Style` who's sole purpose is really to define a `ControlTemplate` that specifies what content an `Adorner` should have that is applied to controls that currently have focus. Here is a short example taken from the linked page on MSDN:

```
<Style x:Key="MyFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="-2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red" 
                    StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This `Style` would add a red `Rectangle` around each focused control that has it applied.

Comment: Note that `FocusVisualStyle` only works for focus obtained via keyboard navigation. Using the mouse or setting it from code will not use this style. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567(v=vs.110).aspx) `Any mouse action or programmatic focus change disables the mode for focus visual styles.`

Comment: And in more detail: "`Focus visual styles act exclusively for keyboard focus. As such, focus visual styles are a type of accessibility feature. If you want UI changes for any type of focus, whether via mouse, keyboard, or programmatically, then you should not use focus visual styles, and should instead use setters and triggers in styles or templates that are working from the value of general focus properties such as IsFocused or IsFocusWithin.`"